# android : using opencv for image recognition

Tags: android, opencv, image-recognition

I want my android app to recognise millions of images. So i want to know if openCv is a choice for this solution. I want an image to be compared against a huge ( millions ) of reference images and find if any matches . Is this can be achieved with efficiency when opencv is used

Comment: Computations of that scale probably better done on a server and the results returned to the client.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon the algorithm you're using the time varies.

Here's [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748900/logo-detection-using-opencv) about what you're asking. As Tushar stated it's better to do these computations on a server and return the results rather than on the client device. Although the code I'm going to post below showed tremendous speed on a Galaxy SIII.

Also, if you'd like some sample code, take a look [here](https://github.com/torcellite/imageComparator).